# How to create Multi filter Gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter, gallery

The product **Red Small** has the property Size **small** BUT NOT **Medium**.

The product **Red Medium** has the property **Medium** BUT NOT **small**.

If the checkbox is selected for both properties, the plugin checks if there are products that have the property **small** OR **Medium**.

I need that only the product will show which have both selected properties. So **small** AND **Medium**.

How can I do it. can any one help me pls.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
    <div class="multifilter-gallery-wrap">
       <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
                
                 <ul class="multifilter-gallery-nav nav">
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                       <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Color</a>
                       <ul class="dropdown-menu not-close-dropdown" data-display="static">
                          <li class="multifilter-gallery-button" data-filter="red">
                             <input type="checkbox" value="on">
                             Red                                                                              
                          </li>
                       </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                       <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true" data-display="static">Size</a>
                       <ul class="dropdown-menu not-close-dropdown">
                          <li class="multifilter-gallery-button" data-filter="small">
                             <input type="checkbox">
                             Small                     
                          </li>
                          <li class="multifilter-gallery-button" data-filter="medium">
                             <input type="checkbox">
                             Medium                  
                          </li>
                       </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="multifilter-gallery-button clear btn btn-secondary" data-filter="all">Reset</li>
                 </ul>
            </nav>

             <div class="row mt-5" >
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-3 multifilter-gallery-box red small ">
                    <div class="bg-success m-2" style="height: 200px">
                        <h2 class="text-white">Red Small</h2>
                   </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4 multifilter-gallery-box red medium ">
                   <div class="bg-success m-2" style="height: 200px">
                        <h2 class="text-white">Red medium</h2>
                   </div>
                </div>
             </div>
             <!--end portfolio grid -->
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        
    (function ($) {

    $(document).ready(function() {

        // venue filter script
        $(".multifilter-gallery-button").click(function(){
            var value = $(this).attr('data-filter');
            
            if(value == "all")
            {
                $(this).addClass("active");
                $(".multifilter-gallery-button").not(this).removeClass('active').find('input[type="checkbox"]').attr('checked',false);
                $('.multifilter-gallery-box').show('1000');
            }
            else
            {
                $('.multifilter-gallery-button.active[data-filter="all"]').removeClass('active');

                if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
                    $(this).removeClass("active");
                    $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').attr('checked',false);
                }else{
                    $(this).addClass("active");
                    $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').attr('checked',true);
                }

                if($('.multifilter-gallery-button.active').length){
                    var classes = '';
                    $('.multifilter-gallery-button.active').each(function(index, el) {
                        if(index == 0){
                            classes += '.'+$(this).attr('data-filter');
                        }else{
                            classes += ',.'+$(this).attr('data-filter');
                        }
                    });
                    $(".multifilter-gallery-box").not(classes).hide('3000');
                    $('.multifilter-gallery-box').filter(classes).show('3000');
                }else{
                    $('.multifilter-gallery-button[data-filter="all"]').click();
                }
            }
        });

        $('ul.not-close-dropdown').on('click', function (event) {
           event.stopPropagation();
        });

    ///////////

    })
    })(jQuery);
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
                if($('.multifilter-gallery-button.active').length){
                    var classes = '';
                    $('.multifilter-gallery-button.active').each(function(index, el) {
                        classes += '.'+$(this).attr('data-filter');                            
                    });
```

Basically all you need is to remove the "," from the selector. If you have the classes one after another with no spaces, only the elements with all those classes will fit the selection. So where you build your classes variable, you remove the ","